# Split a page into 2 sections

Tags: php, html, css

I currently have the following code.

The circle buttons are basically navigation buttons. The second div is where I have a collapsable list.

I would like to have the list on the right-hand side of the navigation.

I have attempted to wrap the divs and also use float as left, for some reason it is still not working. If someone could assist?

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255, 43, 62, 0.84);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 10px;
}


.links > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}



.round-button {
    width:8%;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    margin: 10%;
    border-radius: 110%;
    border:3px solid #56660d;
    overflow:hidden;

    background: #abc729;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background: #56660d;
}
.round-button a {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:45%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    text-align:center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:0.70em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    position: relative;

}
```

```html
<div class="circle-flex-center cirlce-position-ref circle-full-height">
        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-personaldetails" class="round-button">Personal & Placement Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-tutordetails" class="round-button">Tutor Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-placementassignment" class="round-button">Assignments & Examples</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-markscheme" class="round-button">Mark Scheme</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-submission" class="round-button">Submission</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapseone" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Monthly Reflection
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseone" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                    <div class="panel-body">
sjfhdkjs
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsetwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Reflection Example
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
adfjkldsf
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsethree" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Tutor Visits
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsethree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
dilfsklsdgs
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsefour" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Reports
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
sfjksdf
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsefive" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Report Example
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsefive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
difks;ldsf

</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS?

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz added

Comment: Too many things wrong with that structure. To your question, add the following to your CSS: `.panel-group{float: right;}`

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz it's my first time working with HTML, collapsableCSS, PHP, will be working on cleaning the structure a little later. Thank you for the help! It did manage collapsible list to the right, but will play around with it to make it towards the top of the page. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit restructured your CSS. I hope that helps.

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255, 43, 62, 0.84);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 10px;
}

.circle-flex-center{
  width: 80px;
}

.round-button{
  text-align: center;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  border:3px solid #56660d;
  background-color: #abc729;
  border-radius: 110%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
  float: left;
}
.round-button a{
  padding: 5px;
  line-height:1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:0.60em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.round-button:hover{
   background: #56660d;
}
.panel-group{
   float: right;
   margin-top: -65%;
}


.links > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-flex-center cirlce-position-ref circle-full-height">
        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-personaldetails" >Personal & Placement Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-tutordetails" >Tutor Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-placementassignment" >Assignments & Examples</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-markscheme" >Mark Scheme</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="round-button">
            <div class="round-button-circle">
                <a href="student-submission" >Submission</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapseone" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Monthly Reflection
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseone" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                    <div class="panel-body">
sjfhdkjs
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsetwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Reflection Example
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
adfjkldsf
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsethree" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Tutor Visits
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsethree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
dilfsklsdgs
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsefour" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Reports
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
sfjksdf
 </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapsefive" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                            Report Example
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsefive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
difks;ldsf

</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```